# Translate and explain some C++ bit operations to C#

Tags: c#, c++, bit-manipulation

Can you help me with the translation to c# of this 3rd part API method:

I also didnt understand everything that is happening at the bit operations..

```
inline void SetBits(unsigned long& aValue,unsigned int aData,unsigned int aPosition,unsigned int aLength)
{
    unsigned int datamask;   // data mask, before aPosition shift

    if (aLength == 32)
        datamask = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    else
        datamask = (1L << aLength) - 1;

    aValue &= ~(datamask << aPosition);             // Clear bits
    aValue |= (aData & datamask) << aPosition;      // Set value
}
```

Im getting this error in C# version:

> Error Operator '<<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'long' and 'uint'
>
> Error Operator '<<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'uint' and 'uint'

EDITED:

I think this solution is ok:

```
    private void SetBits(ref uint value, uint data, int position, int length)
    {
        uint datamask;   // data mask, before position shift

        if (length >= 32)
            datamask = 0xFFFFFFFF;
        else
            datamask = ((uint)1 << length) - 1;

        value &= ~(datamask << position);             // Clear bits
        value |= (data & datamask) << position;      // Set value
    }
```

Comment: Look here for a bit of info on bit shifting. - http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpShiftOperators.aspx

Comment: what he want to do here: datamask = (1L << aLength) - 1;. 1L == 0b1? Can I replace 1L for 1 ?

Comment: @Pedro77 It should be safe to just use 1 (or 1U), as the case of a shift >= 32 has been handled separately. So a standard 32-bit uint is sufficient (assuming the standard uint is 32-bit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an example to explain the code (in 8-bit, for the sake of simplicity), lets say `aValue = 01101001`, `aData = 00100110`, `aPosition = 3` and `aLength = 4`:

```
datamask = (1L << aLength) - 1;
```

creates a mask with the `aLength` (4) rightmost bits set to one: `datamask = 00001111`.

```
aValue &= ~(datamask << aPosition);
```

clears the `aLength` (4) bits at the `aPosition`th (3rd) bit position: `aValue = 01101001 & 10000111 = 00000001`.

```
aValue |= (aData & datamask) << aPosition;
```

now copies the `aLength` (4) rightmost bits of `aData` to the `aPosition`th (3rd) bit position in `aValue`: `aValue = 00000001 | 00110000 = 00110001`.

So what this function does, is replace the `aLength` bits at the `aPosition`th bit position in `aValue` with the `aLength` rightmost bits in `aData`.

Answer (score 6):

The count part of a shift operation in C# should always be an int. So try making aLength and aPosition into an int instead of a uint. [See here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1sway8w%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

> I didnt understand what happens here: `datamask = (1L << aLength) - 1;`

This code creates a mask with the first (right-most) `aLength` bits set to 1. The code uses a special rule for aLength=32 because this formula would overflow.